# Should Paris museums be booked online?

Tags: paris, museums

I'd like to know whether the museums in Paris, say the Pompidou, should be booked in advance in order to skip the long queues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitively yes, e.g., on [FNAC Tickets](http://www.fnactickets.com) site.

Type for instance *Louvre* in the search box, and you get the link to book a ticket for the Louvre Museum.

Alternatively, once in Paris, you can go to any FNAC store and buy a ticket for the Louvre, without the long queue in front of the museum.

Comment: I think you can entry to Louvre by free some day after 16h. I would like art, but normally I stay just few hours on Louvre.

Answer (score 3):

So booking in advance definitely seems to have benefits.. An example below for Paris pass

[Paris Pass](http://www.parispass.com/)

> Discover the joy of sightseeing with the Paris Pass, which gives you free entry to the best attractions Paris has to offer. Save time as you skip the queues with fast track entry at many attractions, including the Louvre and Muse d'Orsay, and take advantage of special offers at various Paris restaurants and shops.
>
> Save time as you skip the long queues, and save money with free entry to over 60 Paris sights and attractions. With your Paris Pass, there is no need to use cash, simply show your pass for fast entry. Choose from a two, four or six day pass.
>
> Paris Pass includes:
>
> A free map of Paris
>       Hop-on hop-off tour (Two days until 31 March 2014, one day from 1 April 2014)
>       Free entry to over 60 sights and attractions
>       Additional special offers and benefits at selected restaurants and shops
>       Free use of public transport within Paris Zones 1 - 3 (Metro and public buses) for the validity of your pass
>       Skip the queues with fast-track entry at many of the major sights, including the Louvre, Pantheon, Arc de Triomphe, Muse d'Orsay, Centre Pompidou and many more!

Comment: Paris Pass only makes sense if you visit a lot of places. Also, IIRC, it lets you skip the queue to buy a ticket, which can certainly help at some places, but doesn't normally get you a special entrance if the queue is after the ticket office

Comment: In inclusions it says *Skip the queues with fast-track entry at many of the major sights* so fast track entry probably means *after* ticket office queue is skipped. Still in the worst case scenario even if you avoid standing in ticket line is a major plus.